# How to apply code logic to database records/values?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, web-applications, rules

I'm maintaining a system (in Java, with Tomcat, Spring MVC, and Hibernate) where I have to set access rules for user groups. These rules are saved in a database (PostgreSQL) as records / rows. The logic is very simple. Each user of a company's team belongs (is connected) to a group, and each group has a set of rules.

I have to allow administrators to configure (through a web application) rules for groups, so that each rule has a logic and this is recognized and reproduced on the server side.

I need to define rules with parameters, such as:

- Authentications only weekends.
- Authentications only on weekdays.
- Authentications only at a certain time (from time X to time Y).
- X authentications per day.
- Account expiration from date X
- And so on...

My intention is that the company team can organize itself dynamically, just setting up any rules they want at any time, without the need for maintenance every time their policies change.

I've been searching on google and found nothing about it. I know I can do this in Java code, I would have to tie Java code with values of rules names present in database, something that could change in the future (or between companies), and this does not seem right to me. I'm not sure if this is correct, or preferable (maintainable). I appreciate any suggestions, ideas, or corrections (for real).

**Note:** Team/Groups names may change, but its rules should remain the same (if desired).

### EDIT

The database is already modeled and ready. Groups and rules represent values from two different tables, with no logic at all. Querying these values works trivial. However, as I'm maintaining a web application, I'm in charge of creating a code or procedure that applies logic to the choice of rule values.

I was very clear in my question, but I will add more things:

Imagine that my clients (companies) want a website (a web application) that can manage their employees. Every company has teams of employees (groups), each with its function. Otherwise, some employees are sometimes hired as temporary employees.

My duty is to restrict access to the accounts of users who are part of company teams. This will allow business leaders to restrict things according to their policies.

For any company, the process works something like this:

1. The person in charge defines groups (with names and descriptions).
2. The same person defines restrictions rules for each group.
3. User accounts are created and linked to groups with rules.
4. The accounts are given (assigned) to each person part of the company
   team, each according to their function.

Why should this be done?

- Management
- Control
- Security

Speaking more technically now, I do not know where or how I should implement this **properly**. I know of a way to accomplish this, which is in programming code (Java, in my case), but again, I do not know if this is appropriate.

I also know that it is possible to define users and groups on the database side. But creating and deleting such definitions for each time an employee is hired or his or her length of service is expired can not become practical. My intention is to avoid to the maximum that companies have to spend more money on maintenance (Although sometimes this is obviously impossible).

---

My question based on a real case can be answered indicating to me an ideal way / approach for this type of scenario, either the solution being something that should be implemented in the database, or something done in the application layer, or both, or something else (I do not have experience to solve this kind of situation properly, so I'm here).

For practical purposes, I have decided to describe what technologies I am using in this system. If you want more information, I'll be happy to show you here.

Also, as this is a question that covers a larger context, not specifically databases, and also not specifically web applications, I have decided to put it here (instead of other StackExchange communities).

Thank you.

Comment: (A) I'm not sure exactly what your question is. Can you hone it to a more specific issue? Stack Overflow is not for open-ended discussions or debates.  (B) Are you talking about restricting logins made through Postgres built-in users and groups security feature? Or does your app login to Postgres on its own password and then authenticate users through your own records in your own tables?

Comment: @BasilBourque I just edited my question. Please, when and if you can, take a look. Thank you.